# How to prove [⋀(¬( → ))]⋁(⋀) ≡ p

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I need to prove this using logical equivalences but I'm stuck near the end. Here is what I've got so far.

[⋀(¬( → ))]⋁(⋀) ≡ p

[⋀(¬( → ))] ≡ p    - Absorption Laws

[⋀( ⋀ ¬)] ≡ p      - Conditional Laws

This is kind of where I'm stuck, I had some vague ideas but nothing that would get me to the end of the proof. Thank you for any help.

Comment: What does applying the absorption law get you? (You can click "edit" to show the results of your work.) What's left to prove after you've applied that seems easier to me.

Answer (score 2):

[⋀(¬( → ))]⋁(⋀)

[⋀¬(¬ ⋁ )]⋁(⋀)

[⋀( ⋀ ¬)]⋁(⋀)

(⋀¬)⋁(⋀)

⋀(¬⋁)

⋀true